# NULL in query values resulting in 0.00 in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, null

I have a query that's written dynamically (OO PHP via Joomla) to insert some values into a MySQL database. The form that a user fills out has a field on it for dollar amount, and if they leave that blank I want the value going into the system to be NULL. I've written out the query to the error log as it's running; this is what the query looks like:

```
INSERT INTO arrc_Voucher 
  (VoucherNbr,securityCode,sequentialNumber, TypeFlag, CreateDT, ActivatedDT, BalanceInit,  BalanceCurrent, clientName)     
VALUES
  ('6032100199108006', '99108006','12','V','2010-10-29 12:50:01','NULL','NULL','NULL','')
```

When I look in the database table, though, although ActivatedDT is set correctly to NULL, BalanceInit and BalanceCurrent are both 0.00. The ActivatedDT field is a datetime, while the other two are decimal(18,2), and all three are set in the table structure as default value NULL.

If I run a query like this:

```
UPDATE arrc_Voucher 
   SET BalanceInit = null 
WHERE BalanceInit like "0%"
```

...it does set the value to null, so why isn't the initial insert query doing so? Is it because null is in quotes? And if so, why is it setting correctly for ActivatedDT?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove the quotes around `NULL`.  What's actually happening is it's trying to insert the string `'NULL'` as a number, and since it can't be converted to a number it uses the default value `0`.

As for why ActivatedDT works, I'm guessing that's a date field.  Failure to convert a string into a date would normally result in setting the value to `0` (which gets formatted as something like '1969-12-31'), but if you have [`NO_ZERO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) mode enabled, then it would be set to `NULL` instead.

If you'd like MySQL to throw an error in cases like this, when invalid values are passed, you can set [`STRICT_ALL_TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables) or [`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables) (make sure you read the part about the difference between them) or one of the emulation modes, like [`TRADITIONAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_traditional).

You can try this with the command `SET sql_mode='TRADITIONAL'`, or by adding `sql-mode="TRADITIONAL"` in `my.cnf`.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was the quotes, but couldn't understand why it worked with the date field and not the others.

Comment: In a sane database, you would get an error something like "Cannot insert string into integer field", but MySQL tries to guess what you might have meant, rather than give errors.

Comment: @rjmunro MySQL supports a strict mode as well, I've added that info to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

When you insert NULL into a MySQL database, you cannot insert it with quotes around it. It tries to insert the varchar 'NULL'. If your idea worked, you would never be able to insert the actual word NULL into the DB.

Remove the single quotes when you want to insert NULL.

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting the fields to `NULL` but to strings (`'NULL'`).