# Update INT/DECIMAL field with a null/no value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, null, sql-update

I have a lot of `input` box's. Each input box is linked with a INT or DECIMAL MySQL field and is displayed inside the text box.

The default value of each INT/DECIMAL is a `null` so that when a user first opens the page, nothing is shown inside the text box's.

I have an update query that updates the value of each input box to the respected MySQL Field.

My problem is, for each input box that doesn't get anything typed in, the value of the field switches from a NULL to a `0`.

I am having trouble figuring out a way to update the un-touched input's to a NULL and not have all my untouched values go to 0. Can anyone help?

---

Defining my variables basically goes like:

```
if(nullBlank($_POST['variable1']) == false)
    $variable1 = $_POST['variable1'];
else
    $variable = "";
```

I've also tried: `$variable = null;`

---

My update query basically looks like this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `variable1`= '" . $variable1 . "' WHERE something = something
```

My nullBlank() function

```
function nullBlank($data)
{
  if(is_null($data))
       $value = true;
  elseif(strlen($data) <= 0)
       $value = true;
  elseif($data === "")
       $value = true;
  else
       $value = false;

 return $value;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054638/null-in-query-values-resulting-in-0-00-in-mysql?rq=1 first answer seems to be quite accurate, also this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711649/trying-to-insert-null-if-input-field-left-blank?rq=1 has some code to check and pass in Nulls correctly

Comment: @duindain i figured that is the case. But how do I make sure that if I do have something typed into the text box, that goes through as well. Because if I have a value of `1`, don't have to do "1" ? I have about 100 values getting passed through the SQL

Comment: If it's a number in SQL as well, `\`variable1\`=1` is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $variable1 to `"NULL"` (the string). This way it will end up in the query as `NULL`, which is what represents NULL in SQL.

Comment: do you know of a way that I can structure my UPDATE statement to allow this but to also allow a integer/decimal number as well. I have about 10-100 variables getting passed through this update statement

Comment: As neither NULL nor numbers have to be quoted in SQL, it should work fine as-is. Or didn't I get the qeustion?

Comment: ah well if numbers don't need to be quoted in SQL, then problem solved :)

Comment: Only strings have to, to tell them apart from numbers and to remove syntactical meaning of special characters (like whitespace). Basically.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps change your code for null checks to

```
if (is_null($myVariable)) {
    $sql .= "$columnName= NULL";
} else {
    $sql .= "$columnName= '" . mysql_real_escape_string($myVariable) . "'";
}
```

then call this for each value and it will either null it or quote it

Comment: +1 for escaping the input. Really, @bryan, you should do this with data entered by users before inserting it into a query, to avoid SQL injection attacks. (unless you're using prepared statements, which would be even better ^^)

Comment: Don't worry I am, just kept it simple for proof of concept. Thanks for the help